# tags related to translation

Tags: discussion, tags

I think there is a basic question about tags we should decide on:

**Is the [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) tag sufficient for all translation questions, or do we need some other system? If the latter, what do you propose?**

However we set it up, I imagine we won't need tags like [termos-em-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/termos-em-ingl%c3%aas), which can be replaced by [some tag for translation] + [a tag for expressions or idioms].

Answer (score 3):

**Proposal.** Here's one idea, consistent with the tags made so far:

- [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) for translation from Portuguese into any language, e.g.,

  - [What is the meaning of "saudade" and what good translations into other languages exist?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/80)
- [tradução-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas) for translation to or from English, e.g.,

  - [Is there a Portuguese expression for "raining cats and dogs"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/274)
  - [What's an approximate translation for the phrase "correr atrás"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/213)
- [tradução-espanhol](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-espanhol) for questions of translation to or from Spanish, and similarly for other languages as questions come up. For Spanish, we have two questions so far:

  - [What is the Portuguese equivalent of the Spanish word "ingenio", meaning factory?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/554)
  - [Como se diz "el colmo" em Português?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/547)

**Comment.** This is what I had in mind when I created the [tradução-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas) tag, but I can see a serious downside: we will be mixing questions from Portuguese to English with those from English to Portuguese. The German Language SE has [german-to-english](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-to-english) and [english-to-german](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-to-german), but I'm not sure the best analogue for that in Portuguese.

Comment: I am hoping someone has a better idea.

Comment: And what tag would you propose for questions where someone would like translated into current/contemporary/modern Portuguese some bits from the *Cantigas de Santa Maria* or *Os Lusiadas*? :) I mean, those aren't exactly **not** Portuguese almost by definition, but I can sure see their old language uses throwing people for a loop.

Comment: @tchrist Good question. Among the alternate names on the wikipedia page https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_galego-portuguesa I guess I'd suggest [tag:tradução-português-antigo]. By the way, I am interested to hear alternatives, but I'm not familiar enough with the language (or participating in nascent SE sites, for that matter) to have thought of anything better than this.

Comment: (Thinking about it more...) Or just [tag:português-antigo] if it's not about translation

Comment: We've had some discussion in chat on whether we should allow questions about archaic Portuguese. But if we do, [tag:arcaico] would be enough.

Comment: I fear that [tag:tradução-espanhol] may bring some tricky questions. But most importantly, I think translations from Portuguese to Spanish should not be allowed.

Comment: @E_net4 But you would allow translations from Spanish to Portuguese (like the two above)? In that case, we could simply say, in the tag wiki excerpt for [tag:tradução-espanhol] that it is only to be used for ES=>PT. Such a tag would be nice to have for those familiar with (or native in) Spanish learning Portuguese.

Comment: @Frank that could be acceptable, I guess.

Comment: @E_net4 Okay. By the way, I'm not sure why translation PT=>ES should not be allowed. If you have some reasons for it, I'm curious what they are. Maybe you could make a meta post on the topic.

Comment: @Frank No need to. It simply happens that the site is not meant to gather specialists or learners of the Spanish language. If they want something translated to Spanish, there's Spanish.SE.

Comment: @E_net4 I am not convinced. Maybe I'll make a meta question on it later. Your argument would naturally extend to English as well, and we'd lose things like http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/213/whats-an-approximate-translation-for-the-phrase-correr-atr%C3%A1s (Actually, that's the only example I could find, but it seems quite popular.)

Comment: @Frank Not at all, English would be the only exception because it's the most widespread, the "language of the Internet" and the de facto in Stack Exchange. Therefore, translation questions to English and Portuguese variants make sense, whereas to other languages it does not. Again, we are not gathering Spanish specialists, and we cannot support questions requesting translations to it.

Comment: @E_net4 Okay, I've added another answer (with prepositions that make it obvious what the direction of translation is, so we don't need to expect people to read tag wiki excerpts... because they mostly won't) and another meta Q on whether PT=>X should be allowed. http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/131 You've pretty well convinced me that questions PT=>EN should also be disallowed, since we're not gathering English experts either. Anyway, we can dispute whatever's left in dispute over there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea:

We could use [tradução-ao-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ao-ingl%c3%aas), [tradução-do-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-ingl%c3%aas), [tradução-do-espanhol](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-espanhol), etc. which are less ambiguous than those suggested in my first answer ([tradução-inglês](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas), etc.). Vanilla [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) would again be for translation of uniquely Portuguese terms (like *saudade*) to "close" terms in any other language.